# Understanding process pool : how does a process pool use wait() to reap child process?

Tags: linux, process, multiprocessing

if a process pool is created and there are 10 processes
but my program only use 4 processes
it means there are 6 idle processes

to use a process pool,
generally the pseudo code is like:

```
pool=create_process_pool(M)
for i in 1:N:
    pool.run(task i)
pool.wait()
pool.close()
```

how does the pool decide when to call pool.wait()?
there are some cases:

1 if M>N, for example M=10, N=6, then there are 4 idle processes. For the 6 used processes, when they finished running and exit, they can inform the pool.wait(), but for the 4 idle processes, since they didn't run, how can they inform the pool.wait() that they finishes?

2 if M < N, is a process finishes a task and exit, it may be used for another task. So how can this process know that it will have no tasks any more and so inform pool.wait()

can anyone explain a bit how process pool works in this regard?
thanks!

Comment: It probably depends upon the implementation, but I imagine the idle processes don't actually exist (i.e. are not `fork`-ed), and are just empty slots in the process pool machinery... (and I don't see the relation with [zombie processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process))

Comment: when a child process finishes its task, it is a zombie process, isn't it?

Comment: No, not necessarily. If the parent did `wait` for the child, that child is not a zombie process.

Comment: I tried multiprocessing.pool in python, when N is 10, I used `ps -ef` and see there are 10 processes, so there are idle processes. I know there are different implementations, but they should have a common mechanism

Comment: What makes you believe they should have a common mechanism? If I wanted to implement a process pool in C++, I would have the convention that a process slot with a 0 pid is an empty slot, without any attached process.

Comment: I don't understand this sentence: ` a process slot with a 0 pid is an empty slot, without any attached process.` , what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could implement a process pool (e.g. in C++) with

1. some `Process` class (in particular, knowing the `pid` of each `fork`-ed process). It would have some empty instance (whose pid would be 0).
2. some global array of `Process`-es
3. a `Command` class representing a command to be started (when possible) in the process pool.
4. a `std::deque<Command>` of commands, when possible a `Command` would fire some `Process`
5. an event loop taking account of `SIGCHLD`; when a `SIGCHLD` occurs, you would `waitpid` with `WNOHANG` and get the pid of the ended `Process` so find the actual `Process` instance and do whatever is needed ; that event loop would probably pop `Command`-s to run (so would start non-idle `Process`-es), manage pipes, etc...

Then idle processes would just be represented by a `Process` slot with a zero `pid`; no need to `fork` it explicitly. So they won't be unix processes.... just some internal representation in the process pool software.

My point is that a process pool mechanism don't (necessarily) have to start (with `fork` system call) *idle* processes. It could maintain a pool of process descriptors, and for idle slots mark the descriptor specially. That process descriptor could actually be a `pid_t` and empty slots having `(pid_t)0` which is never the pid of any real Unix process. So there is no need to create processes in advance (but only lazily, as necessary). Hence, no need for idle processes.

I strongly suggest to take some hours to read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It will teach you better than what I could in a few minutes.

As an example, look at the Unix (or GNU) [batch](http://www.gnu.org/software/gnubatch/) (and `at`) command. It does not use any *idle* process. And it does manage a pool of process queues. It is [**free software**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software), so you can study (and improve) its [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gnubatch/gnubatch-1.7.tar.gz).

Comment: 1 the keyword `some` menas `a certain` not `a couple of` right? what is empty instance? you mean `process without task` or no processes at all?  2 the global array of Processes are forked in advance, right? 3 the command here means task? like exec(command) ? 4 this is something like for(;;) do command done?

Comment: my understanding is :the program should make a certain number of processes in advance, e.g, 10. And then if there are 100 tasks, I can run 10 tasks at the same time. And if the program detects that a task finishes, this process becomes idle and can be used to fire another task. is it?

Comment: No, you don't need to create idle processes in advance. Idle processes do not exist, you just mark their slot (inside the process pool manager program) as empty.

Comment: but your 2 `some global array of Process-es` seem to be some idle processes created in advance? aren't they? I still don't get the point, If there are no processes at all, when a task come, the pool has to create a new process immediately?

Comment: ok, thanks for your recommendation. But just my last question as above, can you explain a bit? thank you very much!